# python - require explanation for how recursive code works

Tags: python, recursion

I've started python programming few months ago, and I have a question on recursion in combination with for loops and if statements. My code is as follows:

```
words = []

def create_words(lev, s):

    global words, cnt
    VOWELS = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    words.append(s)
 
    for i in range(0, 5):
        if lev < 5:
            create_words(lev+1, s + VOWELS[i])
```

The result from the code above after calling `create_words(0,'')` is:

```
' words = ["A", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA", "AAAAE", "AAAAI", "AAAAO", "AAAAU", "AAAE", ... and so on ] '.
```

What I would like to know is how this code works recursively when lev =5.
I think when lev =5, 'for loop' goes i=0 to 5, then function ends because the recursive function code `("(create_words(lev+1, s + VOWELS[i]")` is under the `if` condition.

I have no clue how the function keeps running `( AAAAU -> AAAE )` even when the `if` condition is `False`.

Can someone explain it to me...?

Comment: How do you call the function first time?

Comment: create_words(0, '')

Answer (score 0):

Function does not works when condition is False. Check create_words(5,'').
Function basically creates every combination under 5 chars. In recursion, when the sub function exists  the outer function does not(saying just to make sure).

In the first loop creates a new sub function for every vowel. But Since letter A must work first every combination of A should be completed before going to next one. So again in second loop A + every vowel gets generated but again A + A should run first.

This goes on until lev = 5. Once the lev becomes 5, loop goes to the second letter which is E

AAAAU -> AAAE because AAAAU is the end for all the AAAA[X] loop next step is AAA + E because loop ended for AAAA

Comment: "So again in second loop A + every vowel gets generated but again A + A should run first."

it means after last sub function generates AAAAA~AAAAU, code returns to prior sub funtion's for loop, then AAAE is going to be generated.

I thought prior sub funtions were totally stopped when condition is false.

Comment: Every function in the chain contains it's own local state. So when condition is false in the inner most function, upper functions are not affected. That means in the upper function condition is still lev = 4.

Comment: oh now I understand!  thx for ur answer and comments! : )

Answer (score 0):

When `lev =5` then the function call with the value lev=5 *doesn't* add words at all, and ends. But in the process of getting *to* level=5, you've created independent frames of the same function with different values of lev, ranging from 0 to 4. each of those higher frames are the ones adding the words. This is the whole idea of recursion after all.

Taking a simpler example:

```
numbers = []

def create_simple_numbers(num):
    if num < 4:
        numbers.append(num)
        create_simple_numbers(num + 1)
    else:
        print(f"Current value of num is {num}, I will stop executing and return None.")
        

create_simple_numbers(0)
print(numbers)
```

Here, we did call `create_simple_numbers` with num=4 eventually, and that function did stop properly. But the values were appended independently of this specific frame of this function.

Note however, that these are both *bad* functions, relying on external global lists to hold the results instead of doing it properly and returning (or yielding) the results independently.

Anyways, bottom line: the presence of a loop doesn't really mean anything, recursion still creates frames, one for each function call. each frame is independent, with it's own values for it's parameters, and it's own set of outputs. A lower frame doesn't directly impact higher frames, it just stops executing and returns some value when it reaches the end. (here, all your functions return `None`).